# Get for each distinct date the total number of distinct users that up until that date are still positive (infected)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table that tracks swab results. Each user can take multiple swabs on different dates (with precision up to the second) with different results ('Y' -> positive, 'N' -> negative).

Table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE swabs
(
    id          INTEGER    PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id     INTEGER    NOT NULL,
    date_result DATE       NOT NULL,
    positivity  CHAR(1)    NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT chk_swabs CHECK (positivity IN ('Y', 'N')),
    CONSTRAINT uc_swabs UNIQUE (user_id, date_result),
    CONSTRAINT fk_swabs_users FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

This is what the table content looks like after some mock inserts:

```
| ID       | USER_ID  | DATE_RESULT          | POSITIVITY |
| -------- | -------- | -------------------- | ---------- |
| 1        | 1        | 2023-03-18 23:59:57  | Y          |
| 2        | 2        | 2023-03-18 23:59:58  | Y          |
| 3        | 3        | 2023-03-18 23:59:59  | Y          |
| 4        | 2        | 2023-03-19 23:59:56  | N          |
| 5        | 3        | 2023-03-19 23:59:57  | N          |
| 6        | 4        | 2023-03-19 23:59:58  | Y          |
| 7        | 7        | 2023-03-19 23:59:59  | Y          |
| 8        | 5        | 2023-03-20 23:59:57  | Y          |
| 9        | 6        | 2023-03-20 23:59:58  | Y          |
| 10       | 2        | 2023-03-20 23:59:59  | Y          |
| 11       | 1        | 2023-03-21 23:59:57  | N          |
| 12       | 4        | 2023-03-21 23:59:58  | N          |
| 13       | 7        | 2023-03-21 23:59:59  | N          |
| 14       | 1        | 2023-03-22 23:59:56  | Y          |
| 15       | 2        | 2023-03-22 23:59:57  | Y          |
| 16       | 3        | 2023-03-22 23:59:58  | Y          |
| 17       | 4        | 2023-03-22 23:59:59  | Y          |
```

What I'm aiming for is **counting for each distinct day that exists in the table, the number of distinct users that, up until each date, are still positive.**

The result should look like this:

```
| DATE_DISTINCT | TOTAL_INFECTED |
| ------------- | -------------- |
| 2023-03-18    | 3              |
| 2023-03-19    | 3              |
| 2023-03-20    | 6              |
| 2023-03-21    | 3              |
| 2023-03-22    | 6              |
```

What I have achieved until now is a query that given an input date counts the total number of users that up until that given date are still positive.

This query retrieves the number of infected users until '2023-03-20':

```
SELECT COUNT(positivity)
FROM swabs s
         INNER JOIN (SELECT user_id,
                            MAX(date_result) AS max_date
                     FROM swabs
                     WHERE date_result < TO_DATE('2023-03-21', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
                     GROUP BY user_id) m ON s.user_id = m.user_id AND s.date_result = m.max_date
WHERE s.date_result < TO_DATE('2023-03-21', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
  AND s.POSITIVITY = 'Y';
```

I would like to "execute" this query for each distinct day.

Is this the right approach?

Comment: If you have a day without tests, you'll this day in your output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```sql
WITH dates (day, user_id, positivity) AS (
  SELECT TRUNC(date_result),
         user_id,
         MAX(positivity) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY date_result)
  FROM   swabs
  GROUP BY
         TRUNC(date_result),
         user_id
),
date_range (start_day, end_day) AS (
  SELECT MIN(day), MAX(day)
  FROM   dates
),
calendar (day) AS (
  SELECT start_day + LEVEL - 1
  FROM   date_range
  CONNECT BY start_day + LEVEL - 1 <= end_day
),
results (day, user_id, positivity) AS (
  SELECT c.day,
         d.user_id,
         LAST_VALUE(d.positivity IGNORE NULLS)
           OVER (PARTITION BY d.user_id ORDER BY c.day)
  FROM   calendar c
         LEFT OUTER JOIN dates d
         PARTITION BY (d.user_id)
         ON (c.day = d.day)
)
SELECT day,
       COUNT(CASE positivity WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 END) AS num_positive
FROM   results
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY day
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE swabs ( ID, USER_ID, DATE_RESULT, POSITIVITY ) AS
SELECT  1, 1, DATE '2023-03-18' + INTERVAL '23:59:57' HOUR TO SECOND, 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  2, 2, DATE '2023-03-18' + INTERVAL '23:59:58' HOUR TO SECOND, 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  3, 3, DATE '2023-03-18' + INTERVAL '23:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND, 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  4, 2, DATE '2023-03-19' + INTERVAL '23:59:56' HOUR TO SECOND, 'N' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  5, 3, DATE '2023-03-19' + INTERVAL '23:59:57' HOUR TO SECOND, 'N' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  6, 4, DATE '2023-03-19' + INTERVAL '23:59:58' HOUR TO SECOND, 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  7, 7, DATE '2023-03-19' + INTERVAL '23:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND, 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  8, 5, DATE '2023-03-20' + INTERVAL '23:59:57' HOUR TO SECOND, 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  9, 6, DATE '2023-03-20' + INTERVAL '23:59:58' HOUR TO SECOND, 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 2, DATE '2023-03-20' + INTERVAL '23:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND, 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, 1, DATE '2023-03-21' + INTERVAL '23:59:57' HOUR TO SECOND, 'N' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12, 4, DATE '2023-03-21' + INTERVAL '23:59:58' HOUR TO SECOND, 'N' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 13, 7, DATE '2023-03-21' + INTERVAL '23:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND, 'N' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 14, 1, DATE '2023-03-22' + INTERVAL '23:59:56' HOUR TO SECOND, 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 15, 2, DATE '2023-03-22' + INTERVAL '23:59:57' HOUR TO SECOND, 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 16, 3, DATE '2023-03-22' + INTERVAL '23:59:58' HOUR TO SECOND, 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 17, 4, DATE '2023-03-22' + INTERVAL '23:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND, 'Y' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| DAY | NUM_POSITIVE |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-03-18 00:00:00 | 3 |
| 2023-03-19 00:00:00 | 3 |
| 2023-03-20 00:00:00 | 6 |
| 2023-03-21 00:00:00 | 3 |
| 2023-03-22 00:00:00 | 6 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fvCuSmtZ)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I got what you're trying to get, but if I'm not misunderstood you need to count the distinct positive users for each single day

```
SELECT TRUNC(DATE_RESULT) AS DAY, COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN POSITIVITY = 'N' THEN NULL ELSE USER_ID END) AS TOTAL_INFECTED
 GROUP BY TRUNC(DATE_RESULT)
```

Comment: There is no `FROM` clause and this will not get the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

I would try;

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT date_result AS DAY, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM swabs B WHERE B.date_result = A.date_result AND B.positivity='Y') AS NUM_POSITIVE 
FROM swabs A;
```